# Handling of arabic characters in unicode

Tags: python, unicode

When does unicode know when to read from right to left or left to right.

Both in word and in python.

For example,

```
هذا هو الملعون جيد رجل الصباح!
```

If you were to hit backspace, it would be read from right to left.

I printed the unicode bytes representation which is

```
u'\u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0647\u0648 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0644\u0639\u0648\u0646 \u062c\u064a\u062f \u0631\u062c\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0635\u0628\u0627\u062d!'
```

But i did not see anything signifying left to right or right to left.

For normal strings like,

```
Hi how are you, it works from left to right.
```

Shouldnt there be a unicode character or byte to signify left to right or something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, here is a comedic way to explain it.
https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1137:_RTL

> In Unicode, the RLM character is encoded at U+200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK
>   `(HTML &#8207; · &rlm;).` In UTF-8 it is E2 80 8F. Usage is prescribed
>   in the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm.
>    LRM is encoded U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark

The bidirectional algorithm is described here.
http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/

Specifically
ALM U+061C  ARABIC LETTER MARK  Right-to-left zero-width Arabic character

Comment: Note that most of the time you *shouldn't* use explicit direction controls.

Answer (score 4):

The writing direction is a property of each Unicode character. Unicode contains a complex set of properties for each code point (whether it's e.g. a number, a mathematical symbol, whether it is  alphabetic, its case, directionality, which code block it's in - which indirectly defines the script - etc).

For instance, see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0647/index.htm (this is the first character in your example) which includes the bidi (bidirectionality) property [`[AL]`](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Bidirectional_Character_Types) - this encodes "right-to-left Arabic" as the writing direction for this glyph.

There are Unicode characters which explicitly set the direction of the text, but these should not normally be required or useful. The font renderer should already know, for each character it renders, from its Unicode properties, which direction it requires (though text converted from other legacy encodings may still contain explicit direction indicator codes).